# Can't cast SearchView in Fragment (AppCompat)

Tags: android, android-fragments, searchview

I'm trying to listen to text changes in my SearchView from a Fragment but it fails on this line: `menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);`

Exception:

```
        java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.MenuItemWrapperJB cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        at se.xxx.xxx.FragmentList.onCreateOptionsMenu(FragmentList.java:155)
```

My onCreateOptionsMenu (in Fragment):

```
     @Override
  public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  SearchView sv = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search); //crashes here

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

menu layout xml (main.xml):

```
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="se.xxx.xxx.MainActivity" >

<item
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="blabla"
    app:showAsAction="always"
   />
```

Comment: In Fragment class make sure you have imported `android.support.v7.widget` package ?

Comment: android.support.v7.widget.SearchView is imported

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Right way to cast SearchView in AppCompat library:

```
MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
```

Comment: Forgot to answer my own question but this is the way I did it